# NativeScript floating hint

Tags: android, nativescript, android-textinputlayout, angular2-nativescript

I was creating a form in nativescript and I wanted my fields to have floating hints just like [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)  and I found this plugin [nativescript-textinputlayout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-textinputlayout) which techincally does exactly what I want, but the problem is that I am usign angular 2 with my application, and I can't seem to figure out how to use that plugin with angular 2. Can someone help with that? I am also open to other solutions other than using the plugin to implement floating hints

Comment: That is the plugin you'll need. I don't have the exact snippet to use that plugin but here's a sample to use a ui plugin with angular https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-drawingpad/blob/master/README.md#angular so it's going to be `registerElement()` that you need.

Comment: Thank you for the help that totally worked!!

Comment: @OmarEssam Can you post some snippet how you did that. I'm getting some sorta error. thanks

Answer (score 5):

[nativescript-textinputlayout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-textinputlayout) is a "vanilla" NativeScript component. In order to use it with Angular, you need to register it as a valid tag for Angular templates using the [element registry API](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/plugins/angular-third-party.html).

**Example:**

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";

registerElement("TextInputLayout", () => require("nativescript-textinputlayout").TextInputLayout);

@Component({
   selector: "my-component",
   moduleId: module.id,
   templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html"
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

**my-component.component.html**

```
<StackLayout>
   <TextInputLayout hint="my hint" hintAnimationEnabled="true">
      <TextField text="my content"></TextField>
   </TextInputLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@rajlaxmi_jagdale looks like there is a problem in a recent update...

remove below line from mode_modules/nativescript-textinputlayout/textInputLayout.d.ts

**export const iconFontProperty: Property;**

it will work!!